# Counter Effect in jQuery used for displaying number generated from get API object shows isNaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to show the number that I got from my API that I get using JSON.
I would like to put counter effect there and it shows "isNaN".
The API URL return an object and saved the total number in data.data
Could someone help me with this please?

```
<p class="Count member-count" style="color:#BA1823; font-size: 40px;">
                <script>
                    $.getJSON('https://url.com/cmp/server/api/get-total-member', function(data) {
                        var text = `${data.data}<br>`
                        $(".member-count").html(text);
                    });
                </script>
            </p>
            <script>
                $('.Count').each(function () {
                  var $this = $(this);
                  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                    }
                  });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Or `Math.ceil(+this.Counter);`

Comment: 'jquery.min.js:2 GET https://url.com/cmp/server/api/get-total-member net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'

Comment: data return issues

Comment: @VanquishedWombat it's not necessary as the `step` coerces the type to an integer: https://jsfiddle.net/g4qdcw2s/

Comment: Is it possible that the API returned the number as a string, but the Math.ceil() function needs a numeric variable. Maybe, try Math.ceil(parseInt(this.Counter, 10)).

Comment: @VanquishedWombat the format of the response is moot; `step()` will coerce the string value to a valid integer to be worked with as you can see in the example I posted in my previous comment. The issue in the question is due to the `each()` running before the async request has populated the HTML.

Comment: Thanks Rory - I edited my comment a little to make it more of a question befitting your excellent (commented) answer. I grok what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the AJAX call is asynchronous, so the `each()` loop which contains the animation logic, runs *before* the request completes and the `p` element has any content.

To fix this, put the `each()` call within the AJAX callback:

```html
<p class="Count member-count"></p>
```

```js
$.getJSON('https://url.com/cmp/server/api/get-total-member', function(data) {
  $(".member-count").html(`${data.data}<br>`);

  $('.Count').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery({
      Counter: 0
    }).animate({
      Counter: data.data
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.member-count {
  color: #BA1823;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

It's also worth noting that you shouldn't put `<script>` tags in the middle of your HTML structure. Either put them in the `<head>` or just before the `</body>`. Similarly, don't put CSS rules in inline `style` attributes. Put them in external .css files. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c4Lw1n8/) with the full corrected HTML and JS.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Here's a working example without the AJAX request: https://jsfiddle.net/g4qdcw2s/